# How can I capture query sent from Java (tomcat) to an Oracle DB?

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, sniffing

I have an application written by a 3rd party which uses Java/Tomcat talking to an Oracle 12c (12.2.0.1) DB. In its logs it reports "Error inserting into table" but provides no details. In talking with the author's support staff they indicate it is old code and they have no way to give more detail. They say the application is better supported with MSSQL which we do not support in our shop.

I would like to see what the insert statement going to the Oracle DB looks like, but haven't been able to find it in v$sqltext. As an alternative, I was hoping to find a tool like fiddler to view the outbound traffic on port 1521.

Is there specific tool that would allow trapping this traffic which is not encrypted so I can see the "query" sent and the response coming back from the Oracle DB?

A general sniffer may work, but they generally get a lot of extraneous traffic and require a fair amount of mucking about to find what you want.

Note:

As I mentioned in the comments I am not a Tomcat/Java person. I think I found where the classpath is set. Given the windows batch file below, is the "driver" that needs to be replaced bcprov-jdk16-138.jar?

```
set PROJLIB=..\..
set JAVA_HOME=%PROJLIB%\jdk\

set libDIR=%PROJLIB%\appserver\webapps\receiver\WEB-INF\lib
set consoleDIR=%PROJLIB%\bin\lib

set endorsedLibDir=%PROJLIB%\appserver\endorsed

set CPATH= %consoleDIR%\console.jar;%libDIR%\ebxml.jar;%libDIR%\commons-io-1.1.jar;%libDIR%\bcprov-jdk16-138.jar;%libDIR%\xercesImpl.jar

set CLASSPATH=%CPATH%

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32
```

Additional Notes:

The above file is called setenv.bat.

Regarding trying to capture the SQL from the database, the application is not a windows app, it is an app which accepts data from the network and writes it to the DB. This makes knowing precisely when to start and stop monitoring difficult. It seems to be connected for a very short period. It does seem to be able to read data, but not insert.

Comment: Monitoring port 1521 will accomplish exactly zero.  That port is used buy the listener to receive incoming connection requests. Period. Full stop.  Once the listener receives the request, it spawns a dedicated server (or locates a dispatcher) and tells the requesting client to communicate with that server/dispatcher over a different, unassigned  port.  The only traffic on 1521 is the inbound connection request and the outbound message to 'continue on port 4321' (or whatever port the listener chooses).

Comment: Not what I hoped for.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using the Oracle JDBC driver and that you have the ability to replace the JDBC driver in some environment in order to debug the problem, Oracle provides [versions of the JDBC driver that can be configured to log](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/diagnose.htm) the SQL statements that are executed.

An alternative would be to create a [servererror trigger](https://www.dbaglobe.com/2014/02/using-servererror-trigger-to.html) in the database that logs the SQL statements that fail.  I believe that would require that the SQL statement that is failing is well-formed which isn't guaranteed if the third party app is encountering an error dynamically assembling the statement.  If the statement never lands in `v$sql` that may indicate that it isn't well-formed but it's worth a try.

If you're licensed to use the AWR/ ASH tables, you could also try querying `dba_hist_active_sess_history`.  Oracle samples the active sessions every second.  If the failing statement happens to be caught in the sampling, you'd see it there.  If this is a typical OLTP application doing single-row inserts, you may need to run through a lot of samples in order to catch an active session with that statement but that may be reasonable.

Comment: I have full control over the computer. 

I am not a Java person generally and not a Tomcat person specifically, so I am not sure where to find/replace the driver. I am hoping to do this on the client/application side, and not muck around with the DB server.

Where can I find documentation on where to look?

Comment: @PaulStearns - You'd only need to make changes on the app server.  The clean approach would be to look at the `classpath` configured for Tomcat, figure out where in that path the JDBC driver lives, and replace it with the debug build.  The less elegant but potentially quicker approach would be to search the machine for where the JDBC drivers live and just replace them.

Comment: I added a note to my original post regarding Java. If you have a moment I would appreciate it if you could review it.

Comment: @PaulStearns - The JDBC driver will almost certainly have "jdbc" in the file name.  If it's the Oracle driver, it'll be "ojdbc<<number>>.jar" for the past few JDK versions.  I'm not seeing a reference to a JDBC driver in what you posted.

Comment: The thing the OP misidentified as a jdbc driver is a crypto provider. Jdbc driver is supposed to be under $CATALINA_HOME/lib but developers tend to put it in their WAR file instead.

Answer (score 2):

The simples approach is, if you can localize your database session (using `gv$session` selecting your connection `USERNAME`).

Get the `SID` and `SERIAL#` of the connection and activate the 10046 trace using the following statement. (substutite SID for session_id and SERIAL# for serial_num)

```
EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(session_id =>271, serial_num=>46473, binds=>TRUE);
```

*Note that you need permissions for both querying `gv$session` and executing `DBMS_MONITOR` so DBA access is required to grant them to your user*.

Than check the trace file on the database server in folder `trace`, the trace file has a name such as `xe_m005_1336.trc`

Grep for the table name, you schould see someting like this I simulated for failed insert on the table `my_table`

```
=====================
PARSING IN CURSOR #854854488 len=38 dep=0 uid=104 oct=2 lid=104 tim=380974114197 hv=1259660490 ad='7ff08904d88' sqlid='1ttgvst5j9t6a'
insert into my_table(col1) values(:1 )
END OF STMT
PARSE #854854488:c=0,e=495,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=380974114195
=====================
PARSE ERROR #854854488:len=39 dep=0 uid=104 oct=2 lid=104 tim=380974117361 err=904
insert into my_table(col1) values(:1 )
```

Note that this is example of an exception

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "COL1": invalid identifier`

so the statement fails with an `PARSE ERROR`

If the insert fails due to some constraint vialotation, you will see such sequence

```
=====================
PARSING IN CURSOR #715594288 len=37 dep=0 uid=104 oct=2 lid=104 tim=382407621534 hv=3290870806 ad='7ff0032e238' sqlid='17t3q0v22dd0q'
insert into my_table(col) values(:1 )
END OF STMT
PARSE #715594288:c=0,e=245,p=0,cr=0,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=382407621532
=====================
```

The cursor id is `#715594288`so check with this id further in the trace file

```
BINDS #715594288:

 Bind#0
  oacdty=02 mxl=22(22) mxlc=00 mal=00 scl=00 pre=00
  oacflg=03 fl2=1000000 frm=01 csi=873 siz=24 off=0
  kxsbbbfp=2aa71a00  bln=22  avl=02  flg=05
  value=7
=====================
```

Here you see the bind variables passed in the insert, it was the value = 7 that caused the failure.

```
EXEC #715594288:c=0,e=4614,p=0,cr=7,cu=0,mis=1,r=0,dep=0,og=1,plh=0,tim=382407626259
ERROR #715594288:err=2290 tim=382407626283
```

The statement failed in the execution with exception such as

`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02290: check constraint (XXXX.SYS_C0012357) violated`

Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/performing-application-tracing.html#GUID-440D3AD4-B302-408E-8627-FE8032DD09F9) for further details

Comment: While the dB is on a windows server so I couldn't easily use grep, I did do a findstr (windows grep equivalent) on the trace folder (.trc files)before posting this. I searched for the table name, the user name and the machine name, and found no references. I will look into the other items you mentioned shortly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have db access via sqldeveloper....

Go to reports tab, then drill down through data dictionary, database administration, sessions, and finally sessions.

In that view, look for your app's active module(s) and look at the Active SQL tab.
One of them should have your insert statement....

This might help as well...
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/monitoring.htm#ADMQS252

Comment: I looked here first (although I go through Tools->Monitor Sessions) and I cannot see the session. I suspect it logs in, does the insert and logs out. What I would need for this to work is to look at the history of the last 10 minutes.

Comment: ok, try this?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database   Just tweak the filtering...(username, status, etc to catch what you need right after it fails.)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that is **does not work** if the `insert` has a *parsing error*. If you are lucky and the `insert` fails only on e.g. a *constraint violation* (i.e. wrong value inserted but the insert statement is OK) that this works: `select * from gv$sql where lower(SQL_FULLTEXT) like '%insert%my_table%'` (replace `my_table` with the propper table name)

Answer (score 1):

The *ultimate* approach is to trace the JDBC connection on **the client**. Please find the full documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/JDBC-diagnosability.html#GUID-DF070D0F-2D70-4A0F-A542-C4A02BF8F3FD)

In the **first step** you must get the *logging* JDBC driver on the `CLASSPATH`. The logging driver has a suggix `_g` in the name, e.g. `ojdbc8_g.jar` if you use `ojdbc8.jar`

The driver can be found in the Oracle installation in the folder  `jdbc/lib/`

**Further** you must define a *properties* file say `jdbcLogging.properties`  with following content

```
.level=SEVERE
oracle.jdbc.level=ALL
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

**Finally** when you run the Java application you must define two properties

```
 java -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdbcLogging.properties ...
```

This will produce a trace file om the error output where you can find the executed statements.

Example

```
INFO: DRCP Enabled: false
Mar 23, 2021 10:40:31 PM oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement logSQL
CONFIG: BAB2F1 SQL: insert into my_table(col1) values(?)
```

Comment: Is this solution to be implemented on the client (the server running tomcat) or the DB server?

Comment: @PaulStearns this is the *client* configuration, on the host where Java is running.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was downloading WireShark, a sniffer, and monitored the TCP/IP packets.